# Modx Revolution - How to keep input values if form does not verify

Tags: javascript, modx-revolution

Just want to know how to keep text input value if a visitor hits submit and the form does not verify. Anyone have a solution using Modx or Javascript?

I used sessionstorage for dropdown, but not sure how to apply on input text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this piece of Javascript to solve the issue:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var item = window.sessionStorage.getItem('email');
$('input[name=email]').val(item);

$('input[name=email]').change(function() {
   window.sessionStorage.setItem('email', $(this).val());
});
```

Allows me to select text input field and save it until the tab is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using formit for modx it will automatically repopulate the form fields on failed validation so long as you have the form setup correctly ( value="[[!+fi.value]]" )

see the [formit docs](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/formit)

Comment: Hi, but the form wasn't developed using formIt. The way how the other developer had set it up was he added the HTML code of the form in a chunk and then calls to from the content. I tried something like: [[+post.name]] and basically it stores the value undefinitely... so was wondering if there's a js solution or a better modx solution on this? Thanks